# A smooth map $s\colon U\to E$ which is not a section where $\pi\colon E\to M$ is a vector bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

I have a silly question about an example of a smooth map $s\colon U\to E$ which is not a section on $U$ where  $\pi\colon E\to M$ is a vector bundle and $U$ is an open subspace of $M$. According to the definition, $s$ is going to be a section if it has a left inverse i.e.
$$\pi\circ s=id_U.$$
So, if I take $M=U=\mathbb{R}$, $E=\mathbb{R}^2$, and
$$s\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2\text{ with }s(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t)),$$
then is it going to be an example of a smooth map that is not a section? What are the other examples? In other words, I want to understand the nature/motivation for sections.

Comment: You need to take $E=M\times\Bbb R^2$ and $s(t) = (t,\cos t,\sin t)$. This is a section of the (trivial) bundle $E\to M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible motivating example: take a smooth manifold $M$ and consider, for each $x\in M$ the tangent space $T_xM.$ Then, one defines the [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle),  $TM$ so that $TM$ is itself a smooth manifold. It is also a vector bundle. Its elements are pairs $(x,v)$ where $x\in M$ and $v\in T_xM.$ The intuition for this is that we gather together the individual vector spaces $T_xM$ and combine them into a differentiable manifold. Then, the projection $\pi:TM\to M$ sends $(x,v)$ to $x$, as expected, and the existence of a section $s$ ensures that when we send a particular $x\in M$ into $TM$, it ends up in $T_xM$ (considered as a subspace of $TM).$ That is, we want to exclude maps that send $x$ to elements of the form $(y,v): y\neq x.$  This requirement is built into the definition of section for if a map $s$ sends $x$ to such a $(y,v)$ then $\pi\circ s(x)=y\neq x.$

Comment: so, the idea basically that the image of the section $s(p)$ must live in the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$ for all $p\in M$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.